# Snappy on Raspberry Pi 2 Fails to install anything

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

Snappy does not install ANYTHING at all and comes up with the following error:

```
ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy install os-js.ogra
os-js.ogra     23 MB     [=================================================================]    OK    
ERROR: Could not generate AppArmor profile for 'docker_docker_1.5.0.002.json'. Skipping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 187, in <module>
    update_systemd_units()
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 175, in update_systemd_units
    install(f)
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 54, in install
    update_content(f)
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 142, in update_content
    content = generate_systemd_unit(app_triple, pkg_path, fp)
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 78, in generate_systemd_unit
    if not is_allowed(v):
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 61, in is_allowed
    if re.match(WHITELIST, s):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 160, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main
    return mod.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/install.py", line 110, in run
    quiet=not options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/install.py", line 482, in install
    path, user=user, all_users=all_users, quiet=quiet)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/install.py", line 466, in _unpack
    user_name=None)
GLib.Error: click_hooks_error-quark: Hook command '/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook' failed: Child process exited with code 1 (6)
ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy update webdm
webdm      5 MB     [======================================================================]    OK    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 187, in <module>
    update_systemd_units()
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 175, in update_systemd_units
    install(f)
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 54, in install
    update_content(f)
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 142, in update_content
    content = generate_systemd_unit(app_triple, pkg_path, fp)
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 78, in generate_systemd_unit
    if not is_allowed(v):
  File "/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook", line 61, in is_allowed
    if re.match(WHITELIST, s):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 160, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 86, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 82, in main
    return mod.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/commands/install.py", line 110, in run
    quiet=not options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/install.py", line 482, in install
    path, user=user, all_users=all_users, quiet=quiet)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/install.py", line 466, in _unpack
    user_name=None)
GLib.Error: click_hooks_error-quark: Hook command '/usr/lib/snappy-systemd/systemd-snappyhook' failed: Child process exited with code 1 (6)
ubuntu@localhost:~$
```

Comment: have you set the system time?

Comment: yes
timedatectl set-ntp true

Comment: Anyone....there????

Answer (score 0):

Platform: Raspberry PI 2 1GB
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/snappy/

- Same exact sequence of Error Messages except I was trying to install Docker.

> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 160, in match
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
>   TypeError: expected string or buffer
>   ```

- A long list of other issues (i.e., commands in the Snappy tutorials/guides would fail)

  `$ Snappy list -v`

After a dozen or so consecutive issues decided to go for the [unofficial Raspberry Pi 2 image](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/)

[Downloaded](http://people.canonical.com/~lool/pi2-device-and-oem/pi2.img) the unofficial Raspberry Pi 2 image: (Created: Wednesday, April 15, 2015 at 5:45 PM)

Everything is tracking to the documentation and I have now Docker up and running.